# On partial number bases

Tags: number-systems

As we know, base $12$ is far superior to base $10$, but only outdone by base $2$. $N_b$ denotes a number $N$ is base $b$. This is done by $$N_b=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nb^n$$$$0\le a_n\le b,a_n\in\mathcal{Z}$$ But what if I said there was a more complicated way to express numbers and you use it every day? I'll only go into integers, since that's all I've worked out, but you'll understand what I mean. Time.$$T(\operatorname{seconds})=a_1\cdot60+a_2\cdot60\cdot60+a_3\cdot24\cdot60\cdot60+a_4\cdot7\cdot24\cdot60\cdot60$$Or more generally. $$N_{(b_0,\phantom.b_1,\phantom. b_2,\phantom.\cdots)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\prod_{m=0}^nb_m$$ So This would mean that not every place can hold the same digit. So you might have the number $N_{(4,5,6,7)}=543$ and $N+1=1000$ Where $b_0$ would be $4$ and represent the $3$'s place.

Also just a side note, base $1$ is interesting because $1000_1=.000001_1$

Comment: Interesting analysis , but do you have a question ?

Comment: Are you just stating what you have found, or do you have a question?

Comment: This is just a statement of what I've found

Comment: Base 60 is even better than base 12.

Comment: Don't you want $0\le a_n<b$ rather than $0\le a_n\le b$? You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: @Mirko, yes. Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Comment: @amd ... and base 360 even better (though, with a little problem for having so many different digits), ad libitum... :)

Comment: @JeanMarie 360 doesn’t add any new prime factors XP

Comment: @amb It's true on this point of view ; I mentionned it also because of its  early appearance circa 3500 years ago in babylonian mathematics for the reason it has a real wealth of divisors.

Comment: I'm not in any position to delve too deeply into what you're doing, but you might be interested in this page on [mixed-radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number systems and see if it looks like what you're describing. The Mayans used such a thing; they used linear combinations of $20^0, 20^1, 18\cdot 20^1, 18 \cdot 20^2$, etc.