# How would you go about using $ \pi $ as a number-writing base?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311541/why-can-bases-of-number-systems-not-be-rational-numbers) that any real number can be used as a base in a numerical system. This does seem to me to raise a number of problems.

If you take $\pi$, for example, how would you write the number $2$ in base $\pi$ ?
I suppose $ 2=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x_i}  \pi^i$

Which digit-symbols $x_i$ would you use ? Integers smaller than $\pi$,( ie $ 1;  2;  3$ ), like you would with an integer-base system ? Or something different ?

And how would you find the numerical expansion of any given number ? Just some normal Horner method ?

Any explanation would be apreciated, thanks.

Comment: "how would you find the numerical expansion of any given number ?" Numbers don't have unique representations. For example, given a representation of $1-3/\pi$, if you replace the initial $.0$ with $.3$, you have a representation of $1$. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Knowing that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$, one can use the infinite series expansion of $\sin$ to write any number as a power series of $\pi$ by multiplying both sides by that number.
$$n=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^kn}{(2k+1)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+1}$$

It seems like a quite peculiar way of writing numbers, but that's because $\pi$ is transcendental; we can't write it as a finite sum involving $+,-,\times,\div$ and powers and square roots of integers, and the converse is true.

Comment: @mohamedshawky I completely disagree. Doing that you would have negative rational "figures" ; moreover, what about the fundamental issue which is the uniqueness of such a decomposition ?

Comment: You are looking for [Non-integer base of numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_base_of_numeration) also known as beta expansion of real numbers.